# Finding the region in a Voronoi diagram that contains a point

Tags: matlab, voronoi

I am trying to build a Voronoi diagram using the code in [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50772-polytope-bounded-voronoi-diagram-in-2d-and-3d). However, I have a few points and want to know in which region they fall. This code, like the original function in MATLAB (i.e. `voronoin`) gives two outputs: `[vornb,vorvx]`, one for the vertices and another one for the cells. So, I want to see which region of the Voronoi diagram the point `(x, y, z)` falls in.

I am actually looking for something like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43032-convert-voronoi-cells-to-region-mask?focused=3793374&tab=function) region masking in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you generate your Voronoi cells using the built-in [`voronoin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoin.html) (which takes an N-by-D matrix of points `X` as input) or `polybnd_voronoi` (the linked [File Exchange submission for bounded Voronoi cells](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50772-polytope-bounded-voronoi-diagram-in-2d-and-3d), which takes an additional M-by-D matrix of points `BX` defining a bounding convex polyhedron), you can compute which cell contains a given point `[x y z]` by using only those same input arguments.

For the bounded Voronoi cell case, you first need to determine if your point is inside the bounding convex hull or not. One way to do this is to create a [Delaunay triangulation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation.html) of the bounding points and use the [`pointLocation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.pointlocation.html) method to determine if the point is within the convex hull:

```
DT = delaunayTriangulation(BX);
cellIndex = pointLocation(DT, [x y z]);
```

If `cellIndex` is [`NaN`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html), then the point is not within the boundary convex hull. Otherwise, it is in one of the Voronoi cells. To determine which, first consider that a [Voronoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) cell `C{i}` represents the set of all points that are closer to point `X(i, :)` than any other point in `X`. Therefore, to find out which cell a point `[x y z]` falls into you just have to find the point in `X` that it is closest to. You can do this using [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) and [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) like so:

```
[~, cellIndex] = min(pdist2(X, [x y z]));
```

If you don't have access to `pdist2` (which is in the [Statistics Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html)), you can compute the distances yourself like so:

```
[~, cellIndex] = min(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, X, [x y z]).^2, 2)));
```

Now, `cellIndex` can be used as an index into the output arguments from `voronoin` or `polybnd_voronoi` to get the bounding Voronoi cell.

### Generalize to multiple points:

You can generalize the above to more than just one point `[x y z]`, which will allow you to create a 3D region mask:

```
[PX, PY, PZ] = meshgrid(...);  % Generate regular points in a 3D volume
PXYZ = [PX(:) PY(:) PZ(:)];    % Combine them into one matrix

DT = delaunayTriangulation(BX);      % Create triangulation for boundary
cellMask = pointLocation(DT, PXYZ);  % Find points in boundary

index = ~isnan(cellMask);  % Index of points in boundary
[~, cellMask(index)] = min(pdist2(X, PXYZ(index, :)), [], 1);  % Find cell index
cellMask = reshape(cellMask, size(PX));  % Reshape mask to 3D
```

And the 3D mask `cellMask` will contain index values for points within Voronoi cells and `NaN` for points outside the bounding convex hull.

Comment: I am using the codes at this [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50772-polytope-bounded-voronoi-diagram-in-2d-and-3d] link and I am not sure if the above code works because I get an error saying that index exceeds matrix dimension.

Comment: I am using d = 3 for 3D diagram and [x, y, z] = [0.5 0.5 0.5]

Comment: @Sam: I don't understand. You said in the question you are using `voronoin`, not a File Exchange submission. You should edit the question and make it clearer what you are doing, such as the specific code you are running and sample data.

Comment: I spent several hours on getting a result that makes sense. I think the problem is that you are using DT instead of Voronoi, because DT connects the points, while Voronoi does not, but put the point in the middle of vertices. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Sam: I used `delaunayTriangulation` for only the bounding polyhedron to get its convex hull (i.e. just the points `BX` passed to `polybnd_voronoi`). The calculations that follow that are finding the indices of the Voronoi cells (defined by `X`) for the set of points PXYZ.